# Sharing a hashmaps and some other data structures among different classes

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns

In a web application I want to execute some methods, that belong to different classes. Method calls will be made in a chain (1st method calls 2nd, 2nd calls 3rd... and so on). Each method is going to make some entries or updates in some hashmaps or other data structures. After all the methods are executed, I have to make some updates in my database. Based on values stored in hashmaps.

As per my understanding, I have below options to achieve this:

1. Keep passing the hashmaps, from one method to other.
   I think it's a bad approach.
2. Keep those hashmaps in separate class. Create an object of that class and keep that object passing from one method to other and so on.
   This approach looks better than 1st to me but it still involves passing an object from one object to other leading to a tightly coupled design.
3. Using static hashmaps 
   (or hashtables) or static object of the seperate class made as in option 2.
   (This I think is worse approach because static variables will be shared aming different users).

Please help me in understanding the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply builder pattern to avoid passing parameters between methods. It gives the opportunity of building all your necessary operations in one class and calling them in chain.

Assuming you have 3 operations on the map, I have demonstrated the use of builder design pattern in this scenario

```
public class MyMap {

    Map<String, String> map;

    public MyMap(MyMapBuilder builder) {
        this.map = builder.map;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public static class MyMapBuilder {

        Map<String, String> map;

        public MyMapBuilder() {
            this.map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        }

        public MyMapBuilder doOperationOne() {
            new OperationOne().run(map);
            return this;
        }

        public MyMapBuilder doOperationTwo() {
            new OperationTwo().run(map);
            return this;
        }

        public MyMapBuilder doOperationThree() {
            new OperationThree().run(map);
            return this;
        }

        public MyMap build() {
            return new MyMap(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is your operation classes (dummy operations as example)

```
public class OperationOne {

    public void run(Map<String, String> map) {
        map.put("OpOne", "1");
    }
}

public class OperationThree {

    public void run(Map<String, String> map) {
        map.put("OpThree", "3");
    }
}

public class OperationTwo {

    public void run(Map<String, String> map) {
        map.put("OpTwo", "2");
    }
}
```

And here is how it is called at final

```
MyMap resultMap = new MyMap.MyMapBuilder().doOperationOne().doOperationTwo().doOperationThree().build();
```

The resultMap object keeps the result Map.

Comment: What if I have to send other parameters to run() of different classes. Is builder design pattern fine with it? Since builder design pattern want to save us from object/parameter passing, is it fine to send multiple parameters to the methods?

Comment: Sure. Look at doOperationOne method above. This is not an implemented method. you can pass whatever you want as long as it returns the builder instance. However, because of its nature, you should store your parameters in the builder class. All the aim of this approach is to bring the passed parameters into one place. It's better to create all necessary variables in builder class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the OO route, you shouldn't think about the problem as "data" going through transformations.

Think about what all of that *means*. Make it a collaboration between objects that mean something in your domain. What is the thing that you want in the end? A `Report`? A `Chart`? A `Price`? Call it by name and create it.

Similarly, do not have *transformations*. You can name (and create) intermediary results, if that makes sense from the domain's point of view. For example to create a `Report`, you might need a `Template` first, or whatever.

In short, neither of those solutions look particularly object-oriented to me. But, you can call it functional (if the methods are pure functions), in which case solution #1 or #2 both could work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing multiple internal data structures (belonging to different classes) makes the processing of the incoming web request as fully stateful. It might lead into concurrency issues OR slowness (if you take care of all locks). If the final goal is to make some updates to a database, then either you make them synchronously within the flow OR 'queue' up those events (internally/externally) and process them asynchronously. Each queue record, can hold the info about the DB update. To me, your use case is very similar to 'logging'. A logging framework also needs to make updates to a log file from multiple methods (while processing a single request).